# Starting a sh shell in c doesn't work if I pipe the input to the executable

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe

I have this code right here:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[15];
    int pass = 0;
    int a[30];
    char *args[2];
    args[0] = "/bin/sh";
    args[1] = NULL;

    printf("\n Enter the password : \n");
    scanf("%s",buff);

    execve ("/bin/sh", args, NULL);
    

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code using gcc.
When I run the executable normally with ./myexec the code runs normally. I get the prompt asking for the password and after I input anything the sh shell starts.

But when I do something like `python -c 'print "someinput"' | ./myexec`  the shell doesn't start, or at least it doesn't on the same terminal from which I ran the executable, because I checked for some errno messages and nothing seemed to go wrong but neither ''' ps -a |  grep sh ``` doesn't show any background shells open so I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: _Side note:_ When you use `execve` with a `NULL` last argument, you're blowing away the pointer to environment variables (e.g. `PATH`). Try: `execvp("/bin/sh", args);`

Comment: When you do (e.g.) `echo mypw | ./myexec` your program grabs the first [and only] line. It then invokes the shell. But, the shell sees that _its_ input is a _pipe_ (and _not_ a TTY), so it runs in "batch" mode. It gets an immediate EOF (i.e. nothing to do) and exits [silently].

Comment: You have to work a lot harder to get the password entered and then the shell to read from the terminal.  You would need to redirect the standard input of the shell to the terminal once more before you run `execv()`.  You can probably get away with `dup2(FILENO_STDOUT, FILENO_STDIN)` until you try to redirect the output of the shell (`echo "password" | ./myexec > output` won't work well).  Alternatively, can use `ttyname()` to get the name of the controlling terminal and then open it for reading and duplicate it to standard input, etc.  Fiddly rather than particularly difficult.

Comment: Note that you should use `execv()` rather than `execve()` with an empty environment.  Giving the shell no environment is cruel.

Comment: Note that you should prevent buffer overflows by using `if (scanf("%14s", buff) != 1) { …report error and exit?… }`, also testing that the input worked.  You would have problems with white space in the password too.

Comment: @CraigEstey ty, I understand what is happening now.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the thing is that a buffer overflow is exactly what I am trying to achieve. That buffer is purposefully there so I can override some variables and if overridden correctly the user can have a shell. I guess that I better get that input as a argument to my c code. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `python -c 'print("someinput")' | ./myexec`, you're telling your shell to take the output of the first command, in this case `python ...` and pipe it as the input of the second one (`./myexec`). When the input has been consumed, that's it, there's nothing more that your shell can pipe into the second program.

To make this work, add a `cat` invocation:
`(python -c 'print("someinput")'; cat) | ./myexec`

`cat`, when given no file to read, will just echo data from its stdin, and so it provides you with a way to input data manually in the pipe after `python` completes.